# Chalice error Illegal instruction on Docker Macbook Pro M1

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, chalice

I have macbook M1 with dockerfile setup like this with Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation on Apple Silicon enabled:

```
# Base Image
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.10-slim
LABEL maintainer="lam.nguyenbatung"

ARG LAMBDA_HOME=/opt/lambda_linux

ENV LAMBDA_HOME=${LAMBDA_HOME}

# Install dependencies and tools
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get upgrade -yqq && \
    apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends \
    python3-dev \
    wget \
    libczmq-dev \
    curl \
    libssl-dev \
    git \
    inetutils-telnet \
    bind9utils freetds-dev \
    libkrb5-dev \
    libsasl2-dev \
    libffi-dev libpq-dev \
    freetds-bin build-essential \
    default-libmysqlclient-dev \
    apt-utils \
    rsync \
    zip \
    unzip \
    gcc \
    vim \
    locales \
    && apt-get autoremove -yqq --purge && apt-get clean

COPY ./constraints-3.10.txt /constraints-3.10.txt

# Upgrade pip
# Install constraint with subpackages
RUN pip install --upgrade "pip==23.2.1" && \
    useradd -ms /bin/bash -d ${LAMBDA_HOME} lambda_admin && \
    pip install -r /constraints-3.10.txt && \
    pip install --user --upgrade pip setuptools 

# INSTALL AWS CLI 
RUN curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip" && \
    unzip awscliv2.zip && \
    ./aws/install

# Set the owner of the files in LAMBDA_HOME to the user airflow
RUN chown -R lambda_admin: ${LAMBDA_HOME}

# Copy the entrypoint.sh from host to container (at path LAMBDA_HOME)
COPY ./start.sh ./start.sh

# Set the entrypoint.sh file to be executable
RUN chmod +x ./start.sh

# Set the username to use
USER lambda_admin

# Execute start-airflow.sh
# CMD [ "./start.sh" ]
```

The constraint file look like this:

```
boto3==1.28.45
botocore==1.31.45
jmespath==1.0.1
polars==0.19.2
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2023.3.post1
s3transfer==0.6.2
six==1.16.0
tzdata==2023.3
urllib3==1.26.16
chalice==1.29.0
```

But when I run the command on chalice like: `chalice deploy`, it throw me exception:

> **Illegal instruction**

I look all over the internet, can anyone know how to fix this on Mac M1?